# Hide mouse cursor if idle inside a div after some seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mouse-cursor

How do I let mouse hiding if inactive and inside a specific div ?
I have the "html5gallery-box-0" div on my website, and I need the mouse to hide if the user let it idle over/inside the div after a couple of seconds.
Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1Lsqpm3y/1/) I'm working on.

And here's the js I'm using to hide the mouse when it's inactive.

```
$(function () {
    var timer;
    var fadeInBuffer = false;
    $(document).mousemove(function () {
        if (!fadeInBuffer) {
            if (timer) {
                console.log("clearTimer");
                clearTimeout(timer);
                timer = 0;
            }

                console.log("fadeIn");
            $('html').css({
                cursor: ''
            });
        } else {
            fadeInBuffer = false;
        }


        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("fadeout");
            $('html').css({
                cursor: 'none'
            });
            fadeInBuffer = true;
        }, 500)
    });
});
```

Comment: So the code you currently have hides the cursor after the specified delay, but you want to know how to smoothly fade out the mouse cursor rather than just hiding it instantly? Or are you asking how to have it hide only if over that specified div?

Comment: My fault, I've just translated incorrectly, the problem is that with this code wherever the mouse is, it hide; and i need it to hide the cursor only if its idle inside the "html5gallery-box-0" div.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will work

```
 $(function() {
    var timer;
    var fadeInBuffer = false;
    $(document).mousemove(function() {
        if (!fadeInBuffer && timer) {
            console.log("clearTimer");
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = 0;

            console.log("fadeIn");
            $('html').css({
                cursor: ''
            });
        } else {
            $('.html5gallery-box-0').css({
                cursor: 'default'
            });
            fadeInBuffer = false;
        }


        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("fadeout");
            $('.html5gallery-box-0').css({
                cursor: 'none'
            });

            fadeInBuffer = true;
        }, 2000)
    });
    $('.html5gallery-box-0').css({
        cursor: 'default'
    });
});
```

and here is the fiddle (if you want to change the idle time just do it, it's on 2 seconds now).

http://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/1Lsqpm3y/4/